# How can I connect redis cloud instance to bull queue?

Tags: node.js, redis, bull-queue

I am trying to connect redis free cloud instance with bull queue but getting error as it is not able to connect.

1. I tried below code:

```
const Bull = require("bull");
const emailQueue = new Bull("email", {
  redis: "",
});
```

For above code it is giving error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 message.

2. Also tried something like this: using tls field but did not work.

```
const Bull = require("bull");
const emailQueue = new Bull("email", {
   redis: {
     port: "",
     host: "",
     tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
   },
});
```

Note: I am using redis free cloud instance with bull queue and also download redis insight desktop application. I have added database to redis insight desktop app and it is connected but in node application it is not working. Am I missing any config?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to ensure that your redis server is running locally since you want to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379.

Secondly, to get the connection error you might be having, you can try this:

```js
emailQueue.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

For me, I had no issue connecting to my local Redis server but I could not connect to remote Redis servers especially Redis labs and AWS ElasticCache. From the error message, I realized that I needed extra authentication and I just provided the host, port, username, and password for Redis Labs while I only needed to provide a host, port, and password for AWS ElasticCache, leaving the username as an empty string in my env.

```js
const {
    REDIS_HOST,
    REDIS_PORT,
    REDIS_USERNAME,
    REDIS_PASSWORD,
} = process.env

const emailQueue = new Queue('email', {
    redis: {
      port: REDIS_PORT, 
      host: REDIS_HOST,
      username: REDIS_USERNAME,
      password: REDIS_PASSWORD
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm also having trouble connecting bullMQ to my redislabs instance .. i keep getting this error: 
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

[ErrorReply: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair] 

where you able to connect yours, and if so, how??

Comment: Can you confirm if you provided the correct username and password pair?